# TypeORM return null when nested FindOptions are used

Tags: typeorm

I have a `User` and `Homework` entities. Many homeworks can relate to one user.
`Homework` has `is_done` column. I would like to return a user with only homeworks, which are done:

```
const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne({
    where: { id, homeworks: { isDone: true } }
})
```

User is returned properly, if at least one homework is done. However, user is `null`, if no homework is done. I would expect an empty array returned with a user. Is it possible to do so?